Horizontal scrolling with fixed position content - GSAP
I am trying to build a slider similar to the Expertise section on this website (https://akaru.fr). In the reference site, the content within the slider is positioned absolutely and remains correctly positioned even if the parent element has a transform property.
I have created a demo to illustrate my current progress:


gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".slider-wrap");

let scrollTween = gsap.to(sections, {
  xPercent: (i) => -i * 100 + (i > 0 ? 0 * i : 0), // Stop at xPercent: (-100 * i) + 4.5% for each section after the first one

  // xPercent: (i) => 100,
  duration: (i) => 0.5 * i,
  ease: "none",
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".section-wrap",
    pin: true,
    markers: true,
    scrub: 0.1,
    end: "bottom bottom",
    pin: false,
    start: "top top",
  },
});
   
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  outline: 1px solid rgb(117, 117, 117);
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(134, 134, 134);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: none;
}
.slide2 {
  background: rgb(170, 118, 118);
}
.slide3 {
  background: rgb(116, 184, 139);
}
.section2 {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.slider-wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section-wrap {
  min-height: calc(100vh * 3);
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <h2>section 1</h2>
</section>

<div class="section-wrap">
  <section class="section2">
    <div class="slider-wrap">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <h2>Slide 1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrap">
      <div class="slide slide2">
        <h2>Slide 2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrap">
      <div class="slide slide3">
        <h2>Slide 3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<section>
  <h2>section 3</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>section 4</h2>
</section>



(--> CodePen Demo)
In my demo, I am facing issues with positioning the .slide div fixed at the same place, especially when the parent element has a transform property.

